# Why np.nan==np.nan returns False

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, nan, nonetype

```
print('np.nan==np.nan :',np.nan==np.nan)
print('np.isnan(np.nan) :',np.isnan(np.nan))
print('None==None :',None==None)
```

np.nan==np.nan : False

np.isnan(np.nan) : True

None==None : True

Comment: Also, **`None` is irrelevant** `None` is not `nan`, and really, doesn't act like nan.

Comment: Use `np.isnan(value)` not == to check that - it is well documented.